# CForm onSubmit prints object instead of string

Tags: reactjs

Why do I get `[object object]` result from the `alert`? I just want that to show alert with my inputted username text. This is my code:

```js
  const submitHandler = (username) => {
    username.preventDefault();
    alert(username);
  }
```

```html
<CForm onSubmit={submitHandler} method="post" encType="multipart/form-data" className="form-horizontal">
    <CFormGroup row>
                <CCol md="2">
                    <CLabel htmlFor="hf-email" style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Username:</CLabel>
                </CCol>
                <CCol xs="12" md="6">
                    <CInput 
                    type="text" 
                    id="username" 
                    name="username"
                    placeholder="Enter Username..." 
                     />
                    <CFormText className="help-block">Please enter Username</CFormText>
                </CCol>
     </CFormGroup>
</CForm>
```

I have pasted the code in [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-mayer-cr7lf?file=/src/App.js) as well, you can try it out there.

Answer (score 1):

Your submitHandler is getting an event object passed to it by the element that is submitting. You need to access the target (the specific element) and the value (the data of that element).

So this becomes:

```
const submitHandler = (username) => {
    username.preventDefault();
    alert(username.target.values);
    
  }
```